# How to use a function from one form in another form?

Tags: c#

I have several forms, but specifically I am trying to make the form1 do something whenever the timer in form5 ticks. When timer ticks, it should use the function SimulAuto in form1 to make it change. I start by using a click method to initiate form5. Ive tried several things but it just does not work. Or, can anyone help me by giving me an alternate approach to solving this problem. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
 public partial class FormPrincipal : Form
{
    Point[] initialPos = new Point[100];
    ListaVuelos lv = new ListaVuelos();//Declarar una lista de vuelos nueva.
    Sector s = new Sector();
    int MAX;
    Form5 f5 = new Form5();
    PictureBox[] aviones_vector = new PictureBox[100];//preguntar porque no me deja poner el integer MAX como referencia
    public FormPrincipal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

  ...

    public void SimulAuto()
    {
        int minutos = f5.SetMinutos();
        lv.Avanzar(minutos);
        ActualizarPosicion();
    }
    private void automáticaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f5.ShowDialog();
    }
}


public partial class Form5 : Form
{
    int cuenta;
    int tiempociclo;
    int tiempototal;

    public event Action SimulAuto;
    public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public int SetMinutos()
    {
        return this.tiempociclo;
    }

    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cada ciclo dura 5 segundos.");
        timer1.Interval = 5000;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
        tiempociclo = Convert.ToInt32(duracionCicloTxt.Text);
        tiempototal = Convert.ToInt32(tiempoSimularTxt.Text);
        cuenta = 0;

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while ((cuenta*tiempociclo)<tiempototal)
        {
            cuenta++;
            tiempoTranscurridoLbl.Text = "Tiempo transcurrido: " + Convert.ToString(((cuenta + cuenta) * tiempociclo)) + "minutos.";
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Simulación completada.");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start(); 
    }
    private void Form5_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        cuenta = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely you need a modeless dialog. Because if you show a dialog the system chokes?

Comment: Move the timer functionality into its own class. Give the class a reference to the control on `form1` or expose the functionality via an interface. Give the class a reference to `form5` so that it can also do the work necessary there too. Also give your forms more descriptive names than `form-n`. In any non-trivial application, the default names get meaningless pretty quickly.